# How can I embed photo or audio files in DLL or some closed source and access it in c#?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, dll, embedded-resource

I am building a plugin for Unity that forms a set of functional components. Since the components are large and numerous, I prefer to leave the plugin in dll format and I was successful here. But the component icons built in Unity disappear and I want the icons to be attached as a file depending on the plugin.

Inside Main and non-Build project. (original) The component is seen correctly.

[image: Before DLL building inside main project]

How to change the icons is only inside the Unity engine and also the images inside the engine are saved and called and not inside the dll

[image: I Could define scripts icon here]

After building the dll and importing it to the project, other components have the same situation.

[image]

Top information section and how to display the icon in the code.

```
    GUILayout.BeginHorizontal(BoxStyle());
    
    // This part calls the icon from inside the project
    GUILayout.Box(EditorGUIUtility.ObjectContent(target, target.GetType()).image, clean);
    
    var labelStyle = new GUIStyle(GUI.skin.label)
    {
        alignment = TextAnchor.MiddleLeft
    };
    
    GUILayout.Label(pro.Info, labelStyle);

    GUILayout.EndHorizontal();
```

Please help me how to execute a way to close the icons and call them from dll.